# Editing Vs. Downvote/Closing of Question

Tags: discussion, edits, down-votes

I see various questions they are maybe not asked that well on serverfault, but maybe at their core are okay questions.  Also, they perhaps can be changed a little to become a good question.

So it seems with a question like this if one has the rep you can either down vote, vote to close, or edit the question and make it better.  Has anyone ever attempted any analysis of this information and its implications?  Seems like it would be a hard query or set of queries to get right in the sense they would actually be meaningful, but it could still be interesting...

Answer (score 1):

This is a great idea. In particular I'd be interested to see questions that initially get downvoted but bounce back after somebody edits them, which implies the base question was good but the poster phrased it poorly or totally botched the formatting. Come to think of it, it seems like there should be a badge for that; it's essentially [Reversal](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/95/reversal) with editing instead of answering

Comment: Hmmm... a reversal badge for editing questions might help out serverfault from what I have see over time. Although probably problematic from a 'gaming the system' perspective.